# How to write python code that finishes a read from stdin even though the read buffer isn't full

Tags: python, stdin

Python question:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.4.3
```

Searched for the answer to this and maybe didn't know what search to use.

Basically the question is simple.
I have perl code like this and it works perfect.

```
while ($count)
{
    $count = sysread(STDIN,$data,2000);
    if ($count)
    {
        #print "Read $data\n";
        showHex($data);
        $s->mcast_send($data,"$MulticastIP:$MulticastPort");
    }
}
```

What this does, which is exactly what I want, is that sysread, even though given a max read of 2000, will return early if it has read at least one byte and there is a delay, in time, in the incoming data.

**Important: My incoming data is in raw-binary, not newline delimited text.**

I need this in python because the IO::Socket::Multicast in perl doesn't come standard in the perl libraries by default.

But I can't figure out how to do this in python. **Python annoyingly waits until all 2000 bytes are read before returning.**

My python code: go.py (for this example I only read 10 bytes at at time)

```
#!/bin/env python

import sys

while True:
    buf = sys.stdin.read(10)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print "Read %d" % (len(buf))
```

Proof of the issue: go.sh

```
while (( 1 ))
do
    echo Sending ab 1>&2
    echo ab
    sleep 1
done | ./go.py
Sending ab
Sending ab
Sending ab
Sending ab
Read 10
Sending ab
Sending ab
Sending ab
Read 10
```

I know from experience that a read() on any file descriptor returns early if it has read at least one byte and comes to a point where there is no more data immediately available to read, like from a pipe from the stdout output of another program.

```
READ(2)                    Linux Programmer’s Manual                   READ(2)

NAME
       read - read from a file descriptor

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

DESCRIPTION
       read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd into the buffer starting at buf.

       If count is zero, read() returns zero and has no other results. If count is greater than SSIZE_MAX, the result is unspecified.

RETURN VALUE
       On  success,  the  number  of  bytes  read is returned (zero indicates end of file), and the file position is advanced by this number.  It is not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
       requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are actually available right now (maybe because we were close to end-of-file, or because we are reading from a  pipe,  or  from  a  terminal),  or
       because read() was interrupted by a signal.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately. In this case it is left unspecified whether the file position (if any) changes.
```

So how do I accomplish this?

Comment: You haven't shown any of your Python code, but it depends on whether the socket is in blocking or non-blocking mode.

Comment: @chepner, The OP wants to block until data is available, then return the available data (or up to 2,000 bytes of it).

Comment: I realize that, but whether or not your read blocks depends on what you are reading *from*, not in how you call `read`. There is no code to back up the claim that "Python annoyingly waits until all 2000 bytes are read before returning" or to provide a context for why that is true.

Comment: @chepner, They want to read from fd 0

Comment: Now showing my program, simple. I've seen this python behavior for many years.

Comment: Non-blocking reads are not desired, because they would return immediately even w/o any data. My original code was read(2000) but I changed it to read(10) for this example.

Comment: It just doesn't look like python has the basic facility to read like most reads are done. To block until data is available and then to give me what is available. That is standard. Been doing it for 30 years. I want to avoid spinning in a non-blocking read using a timer to slow it down. Perl and C has it... doesn't python?

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out the best way. Unless someone can figure out how to make read behave like C and sysread in perl.
I make it non-blocking like above, but use a select to wait until data is available. Combining both, I get what I want. Wait until data is available and read the available data without blocking. Yea!!!!!!

```
import os
import sys
import select
import fcntl

# Make stdin non blocking
flags = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
    rlist,a,a = select.select( [sys.stdin.fileno()], [], [] )
    for f in rlist:
        try:
            buf = sys.stdin.read(1000)
        except IOError:
            print "IOError"
            buf = []

        if len(buf) > 0:
            print "Read %d" % (len(buf))
        else:
            print "No Data Available"
```

Output: Note.. I never see 'IOError' or 'No Data Available'

```
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
```

Comment: Side-note: Change `if len(buf) > 0:` to just `if buf:`. Collections are truthy when non-empty, falsy when empty, and it's simpler/faster/more Pythonic to use implicit truthiness testing.

Answer (score 0):

Non-blocking mode can be enabled for stdin like shown below. I added some sleep there to prevent CPU hogging.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import time
import fcntl

# Set stdin to non-blocking mode
flags = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdin.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, flags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while True:
    try:
        buf = sys.stdin.read(10)
    except IOError:
        buf = []
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print "Read %d" % (len(buf))
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This will give output like

```
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
Sending ab
Read 3
...
```

Comment: Is there no way to get python to block until data is available and return that data?
I have done programming with stdio, sockets, and comports with other languages (perl, C, C++) and in each case, was able to easily achieve this behavior, in fact, that was the default behavior when reading from either a file descriptor or file pointer.

Comment: It should be in blocking mode by default. As you can see from your example output it requires 4 times to print ab before the read occurs. If we include the newline character from echo ab, that makes "ab\n" * 4 = 12 bytes and then 10 byte read occurs. After that, a new read starts waiting for 10 bytes with 2 bytes in the buffer. Now its enough to read 3 more ab\n's to go over 10 byte limit. Did you forget to include newline character from your calculations?

Comment: I do understand fully what it going on there. What I was referring to was the normal behavior of a blocking read in C and that is... Block until the first byte of data is available and then read until all available data is read or the read size supplied in the call to read is met (which ever is less) and then return. Python's behavior is abnormal... it is .... Read until the number of bytes supplied in the call to read is available, read it, and then return (always a full buffer).

Comment: This is inconsistent even for python itself if you think about how their readline must be implemented. In order for readline to not spin, hogging the processor, it must make use of the normal C style read. They are reading, waiting for a newline. It would be VERY inefficient to read(1) over and over until a newline is found, so they must be using the regular C read(#) under the hood and they parse thru the data until a newline is found.

Answer (score 0):

In the event you are able to use Python 3 instead:

```
while True:
    buf = sys.stdin.buffer.raw.read(10)
    if buf::
        print("Read", len(buf))
```

Then:

```
while (( 1 ))
do
    echo Sending ab 1>&2
    echo -n ab
    sleep 1
done | ./go.py
```

gives:

```
Sending ab
Read 2
Sending ab
Read 2
Sending ab
Read 2
...
```

Comment: That is very Nice!

Comment: Wish I could use that, but I can't guarantee that every device I install this on would have python 3